# checkbox show null value not pass to controller mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass parameter value but when I click download error show **AllDates** show null value. Allstate is a checkbox for if check fetches all data if not check then put date from and Date to then fetch value. But All Date value not pass to the controller and show null value. Any expert tells me where I am wrong.

i am sharing error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'AllDates' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Boolean, System.String,
>   System.String)' in
>   'Lead_Management_System.Controllers.ReportController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

HTML

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report"))
              {
               <div class="form-control">

               Agent  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.agentid, Model.SaleAgentList, new { id = "lblAgent" })


               <div id="lblDate">
                <br />
                Followup Date <br /><br />
                From:  <input type="date" name="cmbSDate" id="cmbSDate" readonly="readonly" />
     To:  <input type="date" name="cmbTDate"  id="cmbTDate" readonly="readonly" />
 Select All : <input type="checkbox" name="AllData" id="AllData" onclick="mcheck()" checked /> <br /> <br />

            </div>

          <input type="submit" value="Download" />

           </div>
           }
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mcheck() {
        if ($('#AllData').not(':checked').length) {
            document.getElementById("cmbSDate").readOnly = false;
            document.getElementById("cmbTDate").readOnly = false;
            $("#AllData").attr('checked', false);

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("cmbSDate").readOnly = true;
            document.getElementById("cmbTDate").readOnly = true;
            $("#AllData").attr('checked', true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index(int AgentID, bool AllDates, string DateFrom, string DateTo)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Real"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_rptAgentStatus", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentID", AgentID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AllDates", AllDates);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", DateFrom);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", DateTo);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);

            lstatus mls = new lstatus();

            Reports.rptAgentStatus rpt = new Reports.rptAgentStatus();
            rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "");
            rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
            rpt.SetParameterValue(0, "SUKH CHAYN RESIDENCE");
            rpt.SetParameterValue(1, "Agent Status "+ DateTime.Parse(DateFrom).ToShortDateString() + DateTime.Parse(DateTo).ToShortDateString());
            rpt.SetParameterValue(2, AgentID);
            rpt.SetParameterValue(3, DateFrom);
            rpt.SetParameterValue(4, DateTo);

            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();


            Stream str = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(str, "application/pdf", "rptAgentStatus.pdf");



        }
```

Comment: not worked that much on mvc but in my previous company we used to have a hidden field to every radiobutton and use to set the hiddenfield value 1 and 0 and in modal we use bit and the name of the particular hidden field which works fine

Comment: can you share a sample idea a just little bit in this scenario  @Ibrahim shaikh

Comment: You're declared `bool AllDates` as parameter but the checkbox has `<input type="checkbox" name="AllData" id="AllData" onclick="mcheck()" checked />`, which `name` attribute of the checkbox doesn't match with action parameter and returns null value. Why not use strongly-typed helpers like `@Html.CheckBoxFor`?

Comment: i don't have model Allstate that's why I am not using   strongly-typed  @Tetsuya Yamamoto